# I got a wallet. dat file, how do I transfer the bitcoin into a new wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet.dat

I have just a wallet.dat files with an unconfirmed transaction on it, can’t remember the backup paraphrase.

I linked the wallet.dat in bitcoin core,

got the wallet I’d where I check and it shows the coin is unspent but unconfirmed. bitcoin is inside but available balance on my Bitcoin core is 00000 and blocks not yet fully syncd.

I tried using procedure with the JSONVIWER but after putting all I was asked, I still got this

E2 -> Error Parse error on line ‘1’ parse error on line^
Expecting‘STRING’, ‘NUMBER’, ‘NULL’, ‘TRUE’, ‘FALSE’
‘{‘, ‘[‘, got ‘undefined

And left me with options ordered than OK.

I don’t know if my question does makes sense but that’s what I’m facing please some should help me